# How I can mark a eMail with Userlabel (not the complete Thread)

Tags: scripting, gmail, gmail-api

I have created this script:

```js
function myFunctionNew() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox subject:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ');
  GmailApp.markThreadsUnread(threads);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var mid = threads[i].getId();
    GmailApp.getMessageById(mid).markRead();
    GmailApp.getMessageById(mid).star();
    
    // ---> so I mark the complete Thread: GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("1").addToThread(threads[i]);
    // Here I want to sign only the one eMail with a User label (e.g. Customer)
    //
    // ---> GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(threads[i]);
    // Here I want to move  only the one eMail to the archive
    
    GmailApp.getMessageById(id).forward("xxxxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com");
  }
}
```

but how I can add a label and move only one eMail which ID I have?

Thanks

Comment: I understand that I cannot label a single email from a thread with a label, but how can I label only a specified eMail when I have the ID?

Comment: Would it be a solution to you to label the whole thread belonging to which this email belongs?

Comment: As an emergency solution "yes". However, this has the disadvantage that all emails are marked with the label. But it may be that not all emails should get the label. I have to go down to the email level.

Answer (score 0):

### Your request can be accomplished with the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api)

- The Gmail API offers you more options than GmailApp, among others labelling individual messages instead of the whole thread
- The Gmail API can be used in Apps Script as [Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)
- All you need to do for it is to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the service by going on `Resources > Advanced Google services....` in your Apps Script editor
- The specific method you need to add a user label to a single message is `Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(resource, userId, id)` with the resource `{"addLabelIds": [labelId]}`
- It is important to use for your requests that concern only one message instead of the whole thread the `message id`, which is different from the `thread id`.
- If you do not know your message id, you need to specify how to find it (e.g. specify the snipept of interest as a search criteria).
- It is also important to know that you need to specify the `labelId` instead of `labelName`, which for user labels opposed from standard labels are distinct.
- If you do not know the label id, you need to loop through all labels by their name until you find the correct one

**Below is a sample code showing how to add a label and perform other operations on single messages with a combination of GmailApp and Gmail API**

```
function myFunctionNew() {  
  var labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list("me").labels;
  for (var a = 0; a < labels.length; a++) {
    if(labels[a].name == "Customer"){
      var labelId = labels[a].id;
      break;
    }
  }  
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:Inbox subject:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var mid = threads[i].getId();
    //retrieve the thread with Gmail API to obtain the ids of the thread messages correctly
    var thread = Gmail.Users.Threads.get("me", mid);
    // retrieve all messages and their id for each thread
    var messages = thread.messages;
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      //retrieve the message id
      var messageId = message.id;
      //perform the desired actions with the message id
      GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).markRead();
      GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).star();
      //now, you need to chose which messages you want to label, for example selectt by snippet:
      var snippet = message.snippet;
      if (snippet == "Paste here the snippet"){
        var myId = messageId;
        //only the messages with the specified snippet will be labelled and forwarded instead of the whole thread:
        Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({"addLabelIds": [labelId]}, "me", myId);
        GmailApp.getMessageById(myId).forward("xxxxxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com");
      }
    }
  }     
}
```